# Setting PHP headers within function / class method

Tags: php, header, buffer, buffering, output-buffering

I have written a class which outputs content type information as a header, however this does not work.  After reading PHP.net it states

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(),
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called.

I am unsure what to do as I cannot hard code the content type everywhere needed.  Does anyone know if it is possible to set headers in functions / classes at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headers were sending correctly all along but I was checking the response of the file I was using and not properly getting the response from the CURL, if that makes sense!  I just needed to use:

```
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The restriction is that the headers must be sent before any other output is sent.

The easiest solution would be to enable output buffering. So you can set headers anywhere till the buffer is flushed.

You can do this ether by using the function [`ob_start`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Or using the [`output_buffering`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) ini directive in php.ini file.

As pointed out by Brad, it is not the most efficient solution as it takes up server memory to buffer the output and delays the sending of first byte.

The best solution would be to find what is sending the output before the `header` call and delay the output if possible.

A good trade-off I found was to enable output buffering using `ob_start` at beginning and flushing the buffer just after the page `<head>` element is generated and all the needed headers are set. This way any further output is not buffered. The only thing to take care of is that all header calls are made before the `ob_end_flush` call.

Comment: Read as: _easiest_ not _most efficient_. Just making it clear. Still +1 for easiest option.

Comment: I have tried to find where I could be outputting anything before this function that sets the header but cannot find anything, I have also tried the ob_start method you have suggested but still no joy. I am using CURL and the GET HTTP method to run the file that I am trying to set the HTTP header.  Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: @LeeTee Either using a browser, CURL or even file_get_contents, the execution of the script would be same. How do you know it is not working? If the error is of output already being sent before the header call, a warning is generated, it should show in your error_log. So how is it not working EXACTLY?

Comment: I have basically stripped all the code out of the file and just called the function that sets the HTTP header and it still does not work.  However, when I go directly to that file from the browser instead of accessing the file using CURL, it works.